# Insert two rows of data into Core Data Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I have a core data stack set up with an entity called Device with two attributes, asset_tag and location. I have two arrays that I have set up like this:

```
var assetTag = ["53","35","26","42","12"]
var location = ["SC", "FL", "NA", "NY", "CF"]
```

The first part of my code loops through the first array and adds each number into the asset_tag attribute like this:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

  for device in assetTag {

        let newArray = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context)

        newArray.setValue(device, forKey: "asset_tag")
    }
```

This adds each value to an array so I can print them out later and this works perfectly. I would like to do the same thing with the second array and add them to my second attribute but when I try, it doesn't add the data correctly. This is what I have:

```
for locations in location {

            let secondArray = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context)

            secondArray.setValue(locations, forKey: "location")

        }
```

When I print out the results, I get a bunch of nill values:

```
[<Device: 0x600000281130> (entity: Device; id: 0xd000000001580000 <x-coredata://22AC91EB-92B1-4E5B-A5A9-A5924E0ADD3E/Device/p86> ; data: {
    "asset_tag" = nil;
    devices = nil;
    location = CF;
}), <Device: 0x60000009f040> (entity: Device; id: 0xd0000000015c0000 <x-coredata://22AC91EB-92B1-4E5B-A5A9-A5924E0ADD3E/Device/p87> ; data: {
    "asset_tag" = 53;
    devices = nil;
    location = nil;
}), <Device: 0x6000002810e0> (entity: Device; id: 0xd000000001600000 <x-coredata://22AC91EB-92B1-4E5B-A5A9-A5924E0ADD3E/Device/p88> ; data: {
    "asset_tag" = nil;
    devices = nil;
    location = NY;
```

I am not sure where those nils are coming from.

**EDIT:**

That looks better but I am getting another attribute called Devices with nils:

```
  "asset_tag" = 12;
    devices = nil;
    location = CF;
```

Also when I print out the results from core data like above, the order of the values is not the same as the order that I defined my array.

```
"asset_tag" = 12;
    devices = nil;
    location = CF;

  "asset_tag" = 53;
    devices = nil;
    location = SC;
```

The results above show 12 and then 53 and CF and then SC but thats a different order than the original arrays that were set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create 5 instances with 2 attributes. Your code is going to create 10 different instances. A Core Data entity is like a class with multiple properties.

The solution is to use an index based loop and assign both attributes.

For a better understanding name the Core Data instance `device` rather than `newArray`. The following code uses an array to keep the instances.

The `assert` line is to check if both arrays contain the same number of items.

```
var devices = [Device]()

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

assert(assetTag.count == location.count, "Both arrays must have the same number of items")
for i in 0..<assetTag.count {

    let device = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context) as! Device

    device.asset_tag = assetTag[i]
    device.location = location[i]
    devices.append(device)
}
```

Side note:

Declare string attributes which are supposed to have a value as non-optional in the Core Data model.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post, I still have some issues. Also I am unable to use device.asset_tag but I had Xcode make my manage object subclasses. Not sure why its not letting me use device.asset_tag,

Comment: `devices` is `nil` because to don't set the attribute. Remember you are only setting the attributes for `asset_tag` and `location` in the repeat loop. The collection is unordered by default. When you read the objects with a fetch request you can pass a sort descriptor to force a specific order. I updated the answer to be able to use dot notation for the attributes.

Comment: yea but devices is not an attribute in my data model, I am not sure where that came from.

Comment: You created the model file, you are supposed to know what you did. An `@NSManaged` property can be an attribute or a relationship. If you don't need any of them delete the attribute / relationship in the model.

Comment: In my managed subclass I have a relationship defined as follows: 

`@NSManaged public var devices: MDM?` Will devices show up in results because it's a relationship in this Entity that I am working with?

Comment: That makes no sense. First of all `devices` implies a one-to-many relationship but the type is a *singular* type (plural type is `NSSet`). Secondly the name implies that's related to `Device` (itself). That's very confusing.